# Use already returned SELECT in another SELECT in stored procedures

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns two result sets. But second SELECT is related on first by join.

Is there a way in MySQL to get rid of repeating? How could I address a SELECT that already was done? Would it increase performance?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `procedure`()
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM users WHERE age > 20;
    SELECT item_id FROM items INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM users WHERE age > 20) ON user_id;
END
```

Comment: your 2nd one will fail as is with a 1248 error. So the above is pseudo code right?

Comment: @Drew, yes, sorry. The point is it's fully repeating the way I do it now.

Comment: Why don't you just select all the columns you need from the second query, and just use that one for both purposes?

Comment: @MattGibson, I think I have just made bad illustration. I my real case I cant do this by real reasons.

Comment: In that case, you're probably best off leaving it as it is, or using a temporary table. Other RDBMses have features for this (e.g. a table variable in SQL Server) but I don't think MySQL has anything better than a temp table.

Comment: @MattGibson if you write a stored proc with a temp table creation (or a non temp table creation), it incurs significant DDL overhead to do the simplest of things. Ought to try it with timing tests.

Comment: @Drew, yeah, I fell worried about that. Also would't temp tables collide with each other, if I call the same procedure a lot of times simultaneously. Are they local to the current call, even if names are the same?

Comment: at the end of the call they drop. I manually drop them anyway cuz I am insanely paranoid. but you don't need to. They won't collide with other peeps because they are on other connections. You can test it with two open gui sql tool windows. Meaning, even outside of a stored proc call, just issue two `create temporary table` calls and sit there looking at them. Same name, different data, they are in separate worlds

Comment: @Drew, so temp tables are local for current connection actually, but since they automatically drops at the end of stored procedure(if they have been created inside one) then it's like it local for procedure. Well, with exception, that it could override temp table, that was made outside of procedure?

Comment: edited answer showing a depiction of it. Don't forget, if you create a temp table it has overhead. If you want a table to be useful and fast, it typically needs indexes (read: more overhead). Good luck.

Comment: @Drew, thank you! I will compare performance for my case. By the way, I think you are incorrect with "at the end of the call they drop". I remade my procedure with temp table and it's definitely does't drops at the and of a call.

Comment: must be why I always manually drop them like I said ... then. But you need to test the theory outside of the GUI tool like workbench to be sure. In other words, if it is like PHP and the known paradigm is create connection, call stored proc, drop connection, then the temp table vanishes

Comment: So, just because they still exist inside workbench or some other GUI, doesn't mean when deployed they won't be dropped. Why? Because the connection is gone.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table items
(
    item_id int auto_increment primary key,
    user_id int not null
    -- FK not shown
);

create table users
(
    user_id int auto_increment primary key,
    age int not null
);

insert items(user_id) values (1),(1),(2);
insert users (age) values (22),(1);
```

### Data at the moment

```
select * from items;
+---------+---------+
| item_id | user_id |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |
|       2 |       1 |
|       3 |       2 |
+---------+---------+
select * from users;
+---------+-----+
| user_id | age |
+---------+-----+
|       1 |  22 |
|       2 |   1 |
+---------+-----+
```

### Query

```
SELECT item_id FROM items 
join
(   select user_id
    from users
    where age>20
) xDerived
on xDerived.user_id=items.user_id;

+---------+
| item_id |
+---------+
|       1 |
|       2 |
+---------+
```

So there, that is your query. One query, 1 result set.

### Depiction of temp tables

This is a view of things of temp tables based on op questions above (not below).

```
drop procedure if exists proc123;
delimiter $$
create procedure proc123 (iParam int)
begin
    insert myTempThing (theI,theWhen) select iParam,now();
end
$$
delimiter ;

-- the following is a temp table NOT created inside a stored proc
-- as in, via whatever programming language you are using
-- will incur time overhead especially if indexes are used, but regardless
create temporary table myTempThing
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    theI int not null,
    theWhen datetime not null
);

insert myTempThing (theI,theWhen) select 123,now();
-- now wait a bit and run the call stmt below

-- again I am still at a workbench prompt

call proc123(456);

select * from myTempThing;
-- two rows
```

Comment: Thank you) But it's not a problem. I need two result sets, and I get them. But I forced now to repeat one select in another(just because they related in my business logic), which I think is bad both for performance and DRY.

Comment: well let's put it this way. If you need 2 result sets, you know what you have to do. The 2nd one is oblivious to the first. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news :P